# Different headers with longtable

Tags: header-footer, longtable, texmaker

I am trying to write a longtable in three pages, for each page I want to create a new header for the same table. is it possible? I only could change the header for first and second page, but when i want to include a new header for third page  i do not get what i want.

The code that i am using is the following:

`````
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[left=2cm,right=2cm,top=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}
\begin{document}

\begin{center}
\begin{longtable}{p{3cm} p{1.1cm}p{1.1cm}p{1.1cm}p{1.1cm}p{1.1cm}p{1.1cm}p{1.1cm}p{1.1cm}p{1.1cm}p{1.1cm}}
\caption[Feasible triples for a highly variable Grid]{Feasible triples for 
highly variable Grid, MLMMH.} \label{grid_mlmmh} \\

\hline 
& NSW$^{+}$ & QLD$^{+}$ & SA$^{+}$ & TAS$^{+}$ & VIC$^{+}$ & NSW$^{-}$ & QLD$^{-}$ & SA$^{-}$ & TAS$^{-}$ & VIC$^{-}$\\ \hline 
\endfirsthead

\multicolumn{11}{r}%
{{ -- continued from previous page}} \\
%{{\bfseries \tablename\ \thetable{} -- continued from previous page}} \\

\hline 
 & QLD-NSW$^{+}$ & SA-NSW$^{+}$ & TAS-NSW$^{+}$ & VIC-NSW$^{+}$ & SA-QLD$^{+}$ & TAS-QLD$^{+}$ & VIC-QLD$^{+}$ & TAS-SA$^{+}$ & VIC-SA$^{+}$ & VIC-TAS$^{+}$\\
 \hline 

\hline 
 & QLD-NSW$^{-}$ & SA-NSW$^{-}$ & TAS-NSW$^{-}$ & VIC-NSW$^{-}$ & SA-QLD$^{-}$ & TAS-QLD$^{-}$ & VIC-QLD$^{-}$ & TAS-SA$^{-}$ & VIC-SA$^{-}$ & VIC-TAS$^{-}$\\ %HEAD FOR THE THIRD PAGE
 \hline 
\endhead

\hline \multicolumn{11}{|r|}{{Continued on next page}} \\ \hline
\endfoot

\hline \hline
\endlastfoot

NSW$^{+}$ &    6.57 &    2.79 &    2.88 &    1.29 &    1.81 &    6.52 &    2.78 &    2.85 &    1.30 &    1.81\\
QLD$^{+}$ &    4.34 &   10.81 &    0.12 &    0.11 &    0.68 &    4.33 &   10.75 &    0.12 &    0.11 &    0.68\\
  SA$^{+}$ &    3.61 &    0.07 &    8.51 &    0.49 &    3.07 &    3.57 &    0.07 &    8.38 &    0.49 &    3.05\\
  TAS$^{+}$ &    2.07 &    0.09 &    0.70 &   10.42 &    1.57 &    2.05 &    0.09 &    0.68 &   10.29 &    1.57 \\
  VIC$^{+}$ &    1.80 &    0.36 &    2.65 &    0.97 &    7.19 &    1.77 &    0.35 &    2.63 &    0.98 &    7.10 \\ 
  NSW$^{-}$ &    6.53 &    2.79 &    2.85 &    1.29 &    1.80 &    6.58 &    2.79 &    2.88 &    1.31 &    1.82 \\ 
  QLD$^{-}$ &    4.31 &   10.75 &    0.12 &    0.12 &    0.67 &    4.33 &   10.81 &    0.12 &    0.12 &    0.69  \\ 
  SA$^{-}$ &    3.58 &    0.07 &    8.41 &    0.48 &    3.06 &    3.61 &    0.07 &    8.51 &    0.49 &    3.09 \\ 
  TAS$^{-}$ &    2.08 &    0.09 &    0.71 &   10.24 &    1.59 &    2.08 &    0.10 &    0.69 &   10.38 &    1.61 \\ 
  VIC$^{-}$ &    1.78 &    0.36 &    2.63 &    0.97 &    7.09 &    1.79 &    0.36 &    2.64 &    0.99 &    7.18  \\ 
  QLD-NSW$^{+}$ &    4.73 &    8.59 &    0.38 &    0.25 &    1.05 &    4.70 &    8.52 &    0.38 &    0.25 &    1.04 \\ 
  SA-NSW$^{+}$ &    4.14 &    0.31 &    6.85 &    0.66 &    2.97 &    4.09 &    0.31 &    6.76 &    0.67 &    2.96  \\ 
  TAS-NSW$^{+}$ &    2.55 &    0.35 &    0.92 &    7.42 &    1.86 &    2.52 &    0.35 &    0.90 &    7.35 &    1.86 \\ 
  VIC-NSW$^{+}$ &    2.46 &    0.79 &    2.21 &    1.11 &    5.54 &    2.42 &    0.78 &    2.18 &    1.11 &    5.50 \\ 
  SA-QLD$^{+}$ &    3.08 &    2.42 &    2.38 &    0.46 &    2.92 &    3.03 &    2.40 &    2.33 &    0.46 &    2.89 \\ 
  TAS-QLD$^{+}$ &    2.24 &    2.09 &    0.61 &    2.55 &    1.64 &    2.19 &    2.07 &    0.59 &    2.50 &    1.62  \\ 
      VIC-QLD$^{+}$ &    2.31 &    2.72 &    1.15 &    0.53 &    3.64 &    2.27 &    2.70 &    1.12 &    0.53 &    3.59  \\ 
  TAS-SA$^{+}$ &    1.81 &    0.21 &    2.07 &    3.02 &    3.16 &    1.77 &    0.21 &    2.04 &    2.99 &    3.14 \\ 
  VIC-SA$^{+}$ &    1.95 &    0.30 &    3.22 &    0.92 &    6.02 &    1.92 &    0.30 &    3.18 &    0.93 &    5.96 \\ 
  VIC-TAS$^{+}$ &    1.51 &    0.26 &    1.43 &    3.13 &    3.57 &    1.48 &    0.26 &    1.41 &    3.09 &    3.56  \\ 
  QLD-NSW$^{-}$ &    4.78 &    8.32 &    0.44 &    0.25 &    1.08 &    4.81 &    8.35 &    0.44 &    0.25 &    1.10 \\ 
  SA-NSW$^{-}$ &    4.23 &    0.40 &    6.64 &    0.63 &    2.92 &    4.23 &    0.40 &    6.65 &    0.64 &    2.96 \\ 
  TAS-NSW$^{-}$ &    2.73 &    0.40 &    1.00 &    6.97 &    1.87 &    2.73 &    0.41 &    1.00 &    7.06 &    1.91 \\ 
  VIC-NSW$^{-}$ &    2.70 &    0.96 &    2.27 &    1.01 &    5.17 &    2.71 &    0.97 &    2.28 &    1.03 &    5.23  \\ 
  SA-QLD$^{-}$ &    3.38 &    2.63 &    2.38 &    0.39 &    2.75 &    3.40 &    2.66 &    2.38 &    0.40 &    2.79 \\ 
  TAS-QLD$^{-}$ &    2.31 &    2.32 &    0.60 &    2.23 &    1.64 &    2.32 &    2.33 &    0.59 &    2.24 &    1.66 \\ 
  VIC-QLD$^{-}$ &    2.57 &    3.25 &    1.03 &    0.48 &    3.36 &    2.59 &    3.29 &    1.03 &    0.48 &    3.40  \\ 
  TAS-SA$^{-}$ &    1.95 &    0.22 &    2.31 &    2.73 &    3.14 &    1.96 &    0.22 &    2.31 &    2.77 &    3.18 \\ 
  VIC-SA$^{-}$ &    2.11 &    0.27 &    3.47 &    0.87 &    5.69 &    2.13 &    0.28 &    3.49 &    0.90 &    5.76  \\ 
  VIC-TAS$^{-}$ &    1.52 &    0.28 &    1.46 &    2.88 &    3.71 &    1.53 &    0.29 &    1.47 &    2.92 &    3.78  \\ 
  QLD-NSW$^{\hat{M}}$  &    3.10 &    0.25 &    3.61 &    2.25 &    2.64 &    3.08 &    0.25 &    3.61 &    2.28 &    2.65 \\ 
  SA-NSW$^{\hat{M}}$  &    3.66 &    3.63 &    0.55 &    2.07 &    1.27 &    3.66 &    3.64 &    0.54 &    2.09 &    1.28  \\ 
  TAS-NSW$^{\hat{M}}$  &    3.47 &    1.94 &    2.75 &    0.56 &    1.85 &    3.44 &    1.93 &    2.73 &    0.55 &    1.83  \\ 
  VIC-NSW$^{\hat{M}}$  &    4.31 &    1.74 &    2.83 &    1.40 &    1.37 &    4.29 &    1.74 &    2.81 &    1.41 &    1.39  \\ ````
  SA-QLD$^{\hat{M}}$  &    3.94 &    2.54 &    3.12 &    0.37 &    2.00 &    3.93 &    2.54 &    3.11 &    0.37 &    1.99  \\ 
  TAS-QLD$^{\hat{M}}$  &    2.63 &    2.56 &    0.44 &    2.95 &    1.44 &    2.62 &    2.57 &    0.44 &    2.93 &    1.44  \\ 
  VIC-QLD$^{\hat{M}}$  &    3.02 &    3.54 &    1.15 &    0.49 &    2.91 &    3.02 &    3.55 &    1.15 &    0.49 &    2.91 \\ 
  TAS-SA$^{\hat{M}}$  &    2.41 &    0.05 &    4.00 &    2.91 &    1.94 &    2.37 &    0.05 &    3.94 &    2.91 &    1.92  \\ 
  VIC-SA$^{\hat{M}}$  &    2.45 &    0.04 &    7.19 &    0.33 &    2.19 &    2.42 &    0.04 &    7.15 &    0.34 &    2.17  \\ 
  VIC-TAS$^{\hat{M}}$  &    1.27 &    0.15 &    0.87 &    4.86 &    2.83 &    1.25 &    0.15 &    0.84 &    4.86 &    2.82  \\ 
  Directional TO Others &  115.40 &   70.93 &   90.39 &   72.60 &  105.45 &  114.95 &   70.91 &   89.85 &   72.89 &  105.71  \\ 
   NET Directional Connectedness &   21.97 &  -18.26 &   -1.10 &  -16.98 &   12.64 &   21.53 &  -18.28 &   -1.64 &  -16.73 &   12.89 \\ 

%Cov Positives
  NSW\_P &    3.63 &    3.84 &    2.04 &    2.77 &    2.96 &    1.78 &    2.20 &    1.71 &    1.97 &    1.41 \\ 
  QLD\_P &   10.24 &    0.49 &    0.49 &    1.53 &    3.67 &    2.64 &    4.14 &    0.38 &    0.56 &    0.44 \\ 
  SA\_P &    0.34 &    8.03 &    0.85 &    2.93 &    2.83 &    0.56 &    1.26 &    2.34 &    3.87 &    1.57 \\ 
  TAS\_P &    0.29 &    1.05 &    9.53 &    2.02 &    0.73 &    3.24 &    0.79 &    4.44 &    1.51 &    4.50 \\ 
  VIC\_P &    0.73 &    2.96 &    1.49 &    6.32 &    2.87 &    1.26 &    3.37 &    3.01 &    6.11 &    3.26 \\ 
  NSW\_N &    3.62 &    3.80 &    2.03 &    2.75 &    2.93 &    1.76 &    2.17 &    1.69 &    1.95 &    1.39 \\ 
  QLD\_N &   10.16 &    0.48 &    0.49 &    1.52 &    3.64 &    2.62 &    4.11 &    0.38 &    0.55 &    0.44 \\ 
  SA\_N &    0.33 &    7.94 &    0.84 &    2.91 &    2.78 &    0.54 &    1.24 &    2.32 &    3.84 &    1.56 \\ 
  TAS\_N &    0.29 &    1.05 &    9.41 &    2.03 &    0.73 &    3.17 &    0.79 &    4.38 &    1.52 &    4.44 \\ 
  VIC\_N &    0.72 &    2.93 &    1.48 &    6.25 &    2.83 &    1.24 &    3.32 &    2.99 &    6.05 &    3.25 \\ 
  QLD.NSW\_P &    9.08 &    0.95 &    0.75 &    2.02 &    4.28 &    2.85 &    4.33 &    0.68 &    0.94 &    0.72 \\ 
  SA.NSW\_P &    0.75 &    7.23 &    1.17 &    3.32 &    3.31 &    0.98 &    1.76 &    2.48 &    3.69 &    1.78 \\ 
  TAS.NSW\_P &    0.69 &    1.43 &    8.22 &    2.62 &    1.35 &    4.04 &    1.43 &    4.86 &    1.90 &    4.79 \\ 
  VIC.NSW\_P &    1.30 &    2.87 &    1.86 &    6.28 &    3.22 &    1.87 &    3.95 &    3.05 &    5.42 &    3.19 \\ 
  SA.QLD\_P &    3.41 &    3.25 &    1.11 &    3.75 &    7.49 &    2.98 &    5.61 &    1.91 &    3.15 &    1.78 \\ 
  TAS.QLD\_P &    2.73 &    1.19 &    4.11 &    2.73 &    3.61 &    8.82 &    4.19 &    4.27 &    1.66 &    4.76 \\ 
  VIC.QLD\_P &    3.45 &    1.83 &    1.26 &    4.84 &    5.78 &    3.57 &    7.89 &    1.96 &    3.41 &    2.27 \\ 
  TAS.SA\_P &    0.50 &    2.55 &    4.26 &    3.65 &    1.97 &    3.66 &    1.88 &    7.58 &    3.68 &    6.45 \\ 
  VIC.SA\_P &    0.66 &    3.56 &    1.51 &    6.09 &    3.07 &    1.28 &    3.13 &    3.47 &    7.12 &    3.18 \\ 
  VIC.TAS\_P &    0.56 &    1.88 &    4.29 &    3.98 &    1.90 &    4.19 &    2.31 &    6.61 &    3.51 &    7.87 \\ 
  QLD.NSW\_N &    8.73 &    1.03 &    0.74 &    2.02 &    4.08 &    2.70 &    4.15 &    0.69 &    0.97 &    0.71 \\ 
  SA.NSW\_N &    0.87 &    6.96 &    1.12 &    3.21 &    3.19 &    0.94 &    1.72 &    2.37 &    3.60 &    1.71 \\ 
  TAS.NSW\_N &    0.76 &    1.51 &    7.57 &    2.59 &    1.33 &    3.64 &    1.39 &    4.49 &    1.88 &    4.43 \\ 
  VIC.NSW\_N &    1.50 &    2.89 &    1.70 &    5.75 &    3.08 &    1.75 &    3.65 &    2.82 &    5.04 &    2.90 \\ 
  SA.QLD\_N &    3.53 &    3.17 &    0.96 &    3.45 &    6.09 &    2.52 &    4.84 &    1.76 &    2.96 &    1.56 \\ 
  TAS.QLD\_N &    2.90 &    1.14 &    3.55 &    2.63 &    3.40 &    6.84 &    3.98 &    3.82 &    1.63 &    4.18 \\ 
  VIC.QLD\_N &    3.94 &    1.66 &    1.12 &    4.40 &    5.11 &    3.20 &    6.73 &    1.75 &    3.14 &    2.01 \\ 
 TAS.SA\_N &    0.50 &    2.75 &    3.76 &    3.50 &    1.94 &    3.19 &    1.78 &    6.18 &    3.57 &    5.55 \\ 
  VIC.SA\_N &    0.62 &    3.83 &    1.44 &    5.71 &    2.93 &    1.20 &    2.96 &    3.30 &    6.51 &    3.02 \\ 
 VIC.TAS\_N &    0.57 &    1.88 &    3.91 &    3.99 &    1.85 &    3.72 &    2.25 &    5.89 &    3.58 &    6.61 \\ 
  QLD.NSW\_M &    0.39 &    3.79 &    2.56 &    2.84 &    1.24 &    1.03 &    1.02 &    2.66 &    2.77 &    2.25 \\ 
  SA.NSW\_M &    3.79 &    0.84 &    2.28 &    1.78 &    1.61 &    1.90 &    1.93 &    1.02 &    0.91 &    1.14 \\ 
  TAS.NSW\_M &    2.36 &    3.07 &    0.88 &    2.14 &    2.84 &    1.52 &    2.21 &    1.37 &    1.68 &    1.27 \\ 
  VIC.NSW\_M &    2.17 &    3.10 &    1.68 &    1.44 &    1.98 &    1.18 &    1.18 &    1.21 &    1.04 &    0.99 \\ 
  SA.QLD\_M &    2.64 &    3.34 &    0.75 &    2.38 &    2.01 &    1.03 &    1.81 &    1.46 &    2.14 &    1.13 \\ 
  TAS.QLD\_M &    2.66 &    0.79 &    3.17 &    1.90 &    1.69 &    2.68 &    1.94 &    2.09 &    1.12 &    2.27 \\ 
  VIC.QLD\_M &    3.45 &    1.54 &    0.88 &    2.90 &    2.08 &    1.20 &    1.95 &    1.36 &    2.24 &    1.43 \\ 
  TAS.SA\_M &    0.23 &    3.75 &    2.64 &    1.77 &    1.63 &    1.22 &    0.87 &    2.15 &    1.92 &    1.98 \\ 
  VIC.SA\_M &    0.20 &    5.85 &    0.48 &    1.41 &    1.88 &    0.30 &    0.73 &    1.22 &    1.42 &    0.76 \\ 
  VIC.TAS\_M &    0.33 &    1.04 &    3.94 &    2.51 &    1.09 &    1.61 &    1.43 &    2.43 &    2.20 &    2.40 \\ 
  Directional TO Others &   86.53 &  105.99 &   94.09 &  122.31 &  105.50 &   87.58 &  100.51 &  103.00 &  105.61 &   99.51 \\ 
  NET Directional Connectedness &   -4.38 &   13.22 &    2.32 &   28.59 &   12.99 &   -3.60 &    8.40 &   10.58 &   12.73 &    7.39 \\ 

  %%%Cov Neg

  NSW\_P &    3.73 &    3.96 &    2.25 &    3.11 &    3.24 &    1.87 &    2.46 &    1.89 &    2.16 &    1.44 \\ 
  QLD\_P &   10.06 &    0.62 &    0.58 &    1.88 &    3.97 &    3.01 &    4.95 &    0.42 &    0.51 &    0.51 \\ 
  SA\_P &    0.40 &    7.86 &    0.97 &    3.08 &    2.80 &    0.56 &    1.13 &    2.66 &    4.24 &    1.60 \\ 
  TAS\_P &    0.29 &    1.01 &    9.15 &    1.87 &    0.64 &    2.76 &    0.71 &    4.04 &    1.46 &    4.12 \\ 
  VIC\_P &    0.76 &    2.92 &    1.53 &    5.99 &    2.66 &    1.20 &    3.05 &    3.02 &    5.88 &    3.39 \\ 
  NSW\_N &    3.75 &    3.98 &    2.27 &    3.13 &    3.26 &    1.89 &    2.49 &    1.91 &    2.18 &    1.46 \\ 
  QLD\_N &   10.10 &    0.62 &    0.59 &    1.89 &    4.01 &    3.03 &    4.99 &    0.42 &    0.52 &    0.52 \\ 
  SA\_N &    0.40 &    7.90 &    0.97 &    3.11 &    2.81 &    0.56 &    1.13 &    2.69 &    4.29 &    1.62 \\ 
  TAS\_N &    0.29 &    1.03 &    9.23 &    1.91 &    0.65 &    2.77 &    0.72 &    4.09 &    1.50 &    4.16 \\ 
  VIC\_N &    0.77 &    2.95 &    1.55 &    6.05 &    2.69 &    1.22 &    3.09 &    3.05 &    5.94 &    3.45 \\ 
 QLD.NSW\_P &    8.86 &    1.10 &    0.85 &    2.36 &    4.43 &    3.11 &    4.96 &    0.71 &    0.89 &    0.78 \\ 
  SA.NSW\_P &    0.83 &    7.03 &    1.29 &    3.41 &    3.20 &    0.95 &    1.60 &    2.74 &    4.02 &    1.79 \\ 
  TAS.NSW\_P &    0.68 &    1.38 &    7.73 &    2.44 &    1.18 &    3.42 &    1.28 &    4.34 &    1.85 &    4.36 \\ 
  VIC.NSW\_P &    1.32 &    2.80 &    1.88 &    5.85 &    2.93 &    1.75 &    3.54 &    2.96 &    5.17 &    3.21 \\ 
  SA.QLD\_P &    3.29 &    3.17 &    1.14 &    3.65 &    6.04 &    2.85 &    4.97 &    1.92 &    3.02 &    1.75 \\ 
  TAS.QLD\_P &    2.62 &    1.17 &    3.80 &    2.61 &    3.07 &    6.86 &    3.78 &    3.78 &    1.58 &    4.26 \\ 
  VIC.QLD\_P &    3.35 &    1.81 &    1.25 &    4.56 &    4.95 &    3.40 &    6.71 &    1.89 &    3.27 &    2.25 \\ 
  TAS.SA\_P &    0.51 &    2.46 &    4.01 &    3.44 &    1.81 &    3.19 &    1.66 &    6.24 &    3.56 &    5.73 \\ 
  VIC.SA\_P &    0.70 &    3.51 &    1.53 &    5.76 &    2.85 &    1.21 &    2.84 &    3.40 &    6.61 &    3.23 \\ 
  VIC.TAS\_P &    0.56 &    1.82 &    4.04 &    3.69 &    1.66 &    3.58 &    2.02 &    5.74 &    3.39 &    6.59 \\ 
  QLD.NSW\_N &    8.94 &    1.22 &    0.88 &    2.49 &    4.70 &    3.14 &    5.03 &    0.81 &    1.00 &    0.81 \\ 
  SA.NSW\_N &    0.98 &    7.14 &    1.31 &    3.59 &    3.47 &    1.04 &    1.78 &    2.79 &    4.03 &    1.82 \\ 
 TAS.NSW\_N &    0.80 &    1.55 &    8.04 &    2.65 &    1.38 &    3.73 &    1.41 &    4.63 &    1.98 &    4.44 \\ 
  VIC.NSW\_N &    1.61 &    3.05 &    1.89 &    6.14 &    3.32 &    1.88 &    3.84 &    3.03 &    5.19 &    3.14 \\ 
  SA.QLD\_N &    3.82 &    3.47 &    1.18 &    3.99 &    7.43 &    2.92 &    5.61 &    2.04 &    3.20 &    1.62 \\ 
  TAS.QLD\_N &    2.98 &    1.26 &    3.94 &    2.84 &    3.48 &    8.91 &    4.30 &    4.12 &    1.62 &    4.61 \\ 
  VIC.QLD\_N &    4.07 &    1.86 &    1.27 &    4.83 &    5.70 &    3.67 &    7.79 &    1.77 &    3.11 &    2.11 \\ 
  TAS.SA\_N &    0.59 &    2.83 &    4.09 &    3.64 &    2.05 &    3.42 &    1.65 &    7.46 &    3.86 &    6.13 \\ 
  VIC.SA\_N &    0.72 &    3.87 &    1.58 &    5.85 &    3.05 &    1.19 &    2.78 &    3.61 &    7.02 &    3.18 \\ 
  VIC.TAS\_N &    0.61 &    1.93 &    4.05 &    3.97 &    1.70 &    3.94 &    2.07 &    6.35 &    3.57 &    7.77 \\ 
  QLD.NSW\_M &    0.42 &    3.68 &    2.67 &    2.80 &    1.20 &    0.94 &    0.90 &    2.72 &    2.93 &    2.25 \\ 
  SA.NSW\_M &    3.75 &    0.87 &    2.36 &    1.80 &    1.58 &    1.90 &    2.00 &    1.00 &    0.85 &    1.10 \\ 
  TAS.NSW\_M &    2.35 &    3.08 &    0.92 &    2.24 &    2.53 &    1.54 &    2.05 &    1.46 &    1.71 &    1.32 \\ 
  VIC.NSW\_M &    2.24 &    3.08 &    1.74 &    1.53 &    1.97 &    1.16 &    1.19 &    1.31 &    1.13 &    0.98 \\ 
  SA.QLD\_M &    2.69 &    3.40 &    0.83 &    2.57 &    2.03 &    1.08 &    1.77 &    1.62 &    2.24 &    1.21 \\ 
  TAS.QLD\_M &    2.61 &    0.80 &    3.15 &    1.93 &    1.59 &    2.47 &    1.94 &    1.94 &    1.07 &    2.13 \\ 
  VIC.QLD\_M &    3.44 &    1.58 &    0.92 &    2.96 &    1.95 &    1.16 &    1.92 &    1.46 &    2.14 &    1.54 \\ 
  TAS.SA\_M &    0.22 &    3.62 &    2.62 &    1.70 &    1.46 &    1.06 &    0.74 &    2.13 &    1.94 &    1.87 \\ 
  VIC.SA\_M &    0.22 &    5.68 &    0.53 &    1.47 &    1.72 &    0.28 &    0.60 &    1.32 &    1.55 &    0.78 \\ 
  VIC.TAS\_M &    0.31 &    0.96 &    3.71 &    2.30 &    0.92 &    1.25 &    1.20 &    2.16 &    2.09 &    2.13 \\ 
  Directional TO Others &   87.69 &  106.94 &   96.25 &  124.92 &  104.67 &   86.94 &  100.85 &  104.21 &  107.24 &   99.38 \\ 
  Directional Inlcuding Own &   96.63 &  114.08 &  104.29 &  131.05 &  112.10 &   95.85 &  108.64 &  111.67 &  114.26 &  107.14 \\ 
  NET Directional Connectedness &   -3.37 &   14.08 &    4.29 &   31.05 &   12.10 &   -4.15 &    8.64 &   11.67 &   14.26 &    7.14 \\
\end{longtable}
\end{center}
    \end{document}
`````

Thanks for your help

Comment: as designed longtable doesn't support this (it is possible to do some things with some undocumented constraints) also but unrelated never put longtable in a center environment. You might prefer xtab which is based on supertab and can do this

Comment: Your posting raises a conundrum: What does it mean to have a continuous table body that spans three pages, but also has three different headers? What information are you trying to convey to your readers? If the table headers are sufficiently different, why not just create three separate tables?